# Using libraries in C# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, fft, libraries

I've been trying to download and use some libraries in my C# project but haven't succeed adding them to the project nor finding anywhere how to do it. The instructions says "simply add the files in the sourcecode folder into your project, compile and have a tea!" (the library is this by the way: http://spreadsheetlight.com/). But I don't think I compiled it properly and it's unable to find the functions/methods in the library and I get an error. Some help would therefore be deeply appreciated!

Thanks in advance!
Axel

Comment: http://www.nuget.org/packages/SpreadsheetLight/

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove the request for a recommendation for a library. That portion is off-topic here at StackOverflow (it asks for opinion about what's "good", and requests links to off-site resources, both of which are inappropriate here).

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that, sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I clicked your link, and downloaded whatever it was. :) It came as a zip folder. Obviously the first thing you need to do, is unzip your folder. Then you should end up with this:
[image]

The important thing here, is the SpreadsheetLight.dll...

Next, go to your project that you want this in, right click on the references folder and click Add reference:[image]

A new window should pop up. Click on the browse tab, find your extracted folder, and select the SpreadsheetLight.dll file:

[image]

Choose OK.

Then view your code, find where all the imports are (i.e. `using System;`), and insert the following:

```
using SpreadsheetLight;
```

or go further to:

```
using SpreadsheetLight.Charts;
```

You can then access members of the library:

[image]

That is how you would generally use a library in Visual Studio... Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

I won't go into using `NuGet`, it's easy and there are more than enough examples / tutorials online for that. I'll explain the non `NuGet` way of manually referencing external libraries.

*The easy way:*

- extract the dll files to your project folder
- add references to the project by right-clicking References > Add Reference > browse to the dll location (inside your project folder) and add them
- in files that reference namespaces, classes, interfaces, ... of these dlls, you'll need to add a `using` statement for those namespaces.

*The better way:*

- make a folder somewhere (on a data disk/partition, in the cloud, ...) called e.g. Libraries where you can subfolder and extract your libraries to.
- add references and possibly `using` statements as mentioned under *the easy way*.
- set Copy Local to true for each referenced dll. This will copy the dll to the project/bin folder upon build. Please note that there are situations where this would not work (e.g. if the dll was already in the `GAC`) but for what you're trying to do, it should suffice.

This does not take into account whether the library is already registered in the `GAC`, if it's an ActiveX lib or any number of exceptions. This is just a way to simply add a library to a `Visual Studio` project.

Comment: NuGet was an interesting alternative, strange that I didn't find any of that when I searched for how to add libraries. Thanks a lot for your answer!